# MERN: Passing _id between components

Tags: reactjs, mern

I'm pretty new to react and JS and I'm hitting a bit of a wall.

I have a MERN stack up and running with a basic read and write API. I'm attempting to link to a new component (using the Mongo id) and grab all the data for that specific id. I have the linking working but I'm unsure how to pass the _id over to the new component. I'd use props if it were from Parent to Child but this is from Child to Child.

Here's my code thus far.

**Container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import MyKids from '../MyKids/MyKids';
import ShowChild from '../ShowChild/ShowChild';
import Home from '../Home/Home';

import './RightPanel.css';

class RightPanel extends Component{

componentDidMount() {

}

render () {
    return (
    <div className="col-sm-9 right">

        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
        <Route path='/mykids' component={MyKids}/>
        <Route path='/show' component={ShowChild}/>

    </div>
)

}

}

export default RightPanel;
```

**Component - MyKids**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Child from '../../Components/Child/Child'

class MyKids extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

let kids = [];

this.state = {
  kidsData: [],
};
}
componentDidMount() {
let kids = [];

fetch( 'http://localhost:3001/api/kids' )
.then( response => response.json())
.then( result => kids = result.data)
.then(() => console.log(kids))
.then(() => this.setState({kidsData: kids}))
}

render() {

  const { kidsName } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className = 'col-sm-12'>
      {this.state.kidsData.map((person, index) => (
        <p>Hello, <Link to={ `/show/${this.state.kidsData[index]._id}` } >{person.firstName}</Link></p>
      ))}

      <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3001/api/kids">
        <label>Enter Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name..." required />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name..." required />
        <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter age..." required />
        <input type="text" name="notes" placeholder="Notes..." required />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Kid" />
      </form>
    </div>
);
}
}


export default MyKids;
```

The 'Link to' works great and I get 'http://localhost:3000/show/5b28f31be5fea7325cfe3883' as I should. However, I've no idea how to grab that ID and use it in my API call to grab that child's data.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did my answer below solve your issue @Nick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ShowChild` component's `render` method, you can get the current location by using `this.props.location.pathname` to get the current URL. You can then extract the `_id` from this by simple string extraction using something like `substr()`

Comment: This works, thanks! Though I'm sure there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do the same thing - _better_ or not would be subjective. In your case, have you considered adding a state management library like `Redux`? There would be some boilerplate and learning curve associated with it, but it might make things like storing an ID somewhere than can be accessed by other components trivial.. Again, read [why you may not need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) before you jump in..